# Testing if two uniform random variables share the same distribution

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, hypothesis-testing

I recently ran into this small probability/statistics related problem, to which I could not find any immediate answers. I have a proposal of a robust solution to the problem and would like to know whether there is a more straight-forward way to do this type of "hypothesis" testing. As a background information, I have fairly much study experience regarding hypothesis testing and frequentist statistics but I don't do them as a trade and it has been (too) long since I last discussed similar problems. It follows that whenever I move out from the normal distributed world and ''standard'' testing, things begin to feel weird.

Let us have two sets of data, $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and $y_1,\dots,y_m$, where $n$ and $m$ are the sample sizes of our data sets. We assume that the data sets are sampled from two uniform  distributions. From this assumption I would like to test whether the uniform distributions are the same, i.e. if they share the same support. For simplicity, I'm interested in the upper bounds of the supports and thus a one-sided test is something that we desire.

**My method:**

For clarity's sake, let's introduce two hypotheses
$$H_0: b=d \quad \text{ and }\quad H_1: b< d, $$

where $b$ and $d$ correspond to the upper bounds of the supports of two sequences of random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n \sim U(a,b)$ and $Y_1,\dots,Y_n\sim(a,d)$ with $a<b\leq d$. The random variables are independent. In other words, $H_0$ corresponds to the situation where in fact $X_i\sim U(a,d)$.

We estimate $b$ and $d$ with reasonable estimates $\hat b := \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ and $\hat d :=\max\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$, respectively. From our assumptions follow that $\hat b \leq \hat d$. Similarly, $a$ is estimated with $\hat a := \min\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. We continue with using a corresponding estimator $\hat B :=\max\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$ to estimate the probability
$$P(\hat B > \hat b \vert H_0 \text{ holds}) \approx P(\hat B > \hat b \vert b = \hat d \text{ and }a=\hat a) = 1-\bigg(\frac{\hat b-\hat a}{\hat d-\hat a}\bigg)^n,$$

when $\hat a < \hat b < \hat d$. The last equality is from the knowledge of cdf of a maximum value a sample of a uniformlly distributed random variable, where we substituted the unknown boundaries of the support with $\hat a$ and $\hat d$.

The probability above should give us a fairly good estimate of a probability of receiving larger maximum sample than we had gathered if the support of the underlying distribution is indeed having  an upper bound of $d$ instead of $b$. If the probability calculated is ''small enough'' or otherwise to my liking, it would be reasonable to argue that then $\hat b \approx b$ is close enough to $\hat d \approx d$ for me to support the null hypothesis. (Alternatively, if the probability is high, it suggests that $\hat b$ is far from $d$.)

**That is, my questions are as follows:**

1. Is this a sensible approach? Are other or better ways to test if two uniform distributions share a support?
2. Is the approximation in calculating the conditional probability justified?
3. Somehow it seems that a more sensible approach would be to directly examine the difference $\hat d - \hat b$, but I don't have a clear idea how to tell when the difference based on sample sizes is ''large enough''. Any clues?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you state how big a difference do you want to detect?  Can’t determine adequate sample size until you give that.

Comment: If I stated that I want to detect differences >5%, where would I incorporate this desired difference? I'm not sure if I'm looking for an adequate sample size, but rather some sample size dependant probability.

Comment: That value (5%) will give a target value to use (although I'm skeptical that's a real value).  I'm traveling for the next several hours so I won't be able to produce an answer until later today.  In the meantime anyone else who has an answer should answer.  Also, I would argue that this kind of question is better answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com as there's more than just mathematics involved.

Comment: If both uniform distributions share the same lower bound ($a$), then just performing a two-sample t-test (but not assuming equal variances) should be adequate as for sample sizes as small as 10, the distribution of the sample means are well approximated by a normal distribution.  If $b$ and $d$ differ, then so will the means.  As to whether a 5% difference in $b$ and $d$ can be reliably detected by the sample sizes you have in mind, those specifics would be needed.

Comment: While my last advice is technically correct, it probably isn't efficient enough to detect differences on the order of 5% for reasonable sample sizes.  I'll write up a much more efficient approach.